# installation of cab was unsuccessful for windows mobile 6.5. No error details in log

Tags: cab, windows-mobile-6.5

I have a provisioning file setup.xml that I want to install on a windows mobile 6.5 phone. I created a cab file, signed and copied to phone, and ran the cab file.
However I get:
'installation of foo.cab was unsuccessful’

I go to Application Data\Volatile\setup.log
The log simply contains the setup.xml file but no error details nor messages.
How to know why it failed?

Comment: Did you test your wap xml with rapiconfig? See here for details http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc500581.aspx. Possibly you can post your wap xml contents here. Another sample is provided here http://community.intermec.com/t5/Device-Management/Provisioning/td-p/70

Comment: Thanks for the link. I found the error in my xml by doing it step by step - adding one parameter at a time, creating a cab, signing and provisioning, then adding the next param. However using rapiconfig produces rapiconfigOut.xml - not sure how this helps.

Comment: RapiConfigOut.xml should contain errors or only the accepted changes.